# push is not working in map function in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I m using Mongo DB and after getting result from aggregate query, map the result of that query and try to push result to array . While consoling that array it returning an empty array, but if we console inside the map there are data s. Below is my code snippet

```
let house = await House.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$houseNumber", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $match: { _id: { $ne: null }, count: { $gt: 1 } } },
    { $project: { houseNumber: "$_id", _id: 0 } },
  ]);

  var arr = [];
  house.map(async (hNo) => {
    var house2 = await House.find(
      { houseNumber: hNo.houseNumber },
      "houseNumber"
    );
    arr.push(house2);
  });
  
  console.log(arr);
```

I m thinking async await making problem here. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't need to run multiple queries within `house.map` loop. You can do `House.find( { houseNumber: { $in: house.map(h => h.houseNumber)}}, "houseNumber" );` to get all the documents in a single query. But your code doesn't even make sense. You already have the houseNumbers from the aggregate function. Why are you making another multiple queries to only get a houseNumber by houseNumber you already have? What do you want to achieve by the House.find ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async function are not supported in .map

You can use `Promise.all` to await every async function result.

```
let house = await House.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$houseNumber", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $match: { _id: { $ne: null }, count: { $gt: 1 } } },
    { $project: { houseNumber: "$_id", _id: 0 } },
]);

// Array of Promises
const promises = house.map(hNo =>
    House.find(
        { houseNumber: hNo.houseNumber },
        "houseNumber"
    );
)

// Array with each promise result
const arr = await Promise.all(promises);
  
// Now you able to log it
console.log(arr);
```

> While consoling that array it returning an empty array
> map is not waiting for an async function result, so at the moment of logging `arr` you have an empty array and `arr.length` pending Promises.

Comment: Thanks @a-kon . It really works fine now, but I was unaware of 'Async function are not supported in .map' . I m using map in multiple async function in routes . Is it right way? Or it will give me problems in future?

Comment: You can use map in async functions, and vice versa. Async functions as the map's callback are supported, but a result is not an array of the function's result, but an array of promises.